# Throwing a terminate exception

Tags: objective-c

I am in the process of learning Objective C using the online Treehouse tutorials I have followed everything step by step up to this point and keep getting an error when I press the button. I am hoping someone can tell me what I did wrong here. The app up to this point is supposed to have a label at the top and a button in the middle of the storyboard when the button is pressed it should change the text of the label. My code is below.

.m file

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Prediction
//
//  Created by Brandon Brown on 7/7/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Brandon Brown. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize predictionLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setPredictionLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.predictionLabel.text = @"Yep";
}
@end
```

.h file

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Prediction
//
//  Created by Brandon Brown on 7/7/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Brandon Brown. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *predictionLabel;

@end
```

This is the error im getting in the console

```
2013-07-07 17:20:09.717 Prediction[14457:f803] -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a44690
2013-07-07 17:20:09.719 Prediction[14457:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a44690'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b0022 0xeb0cd6 0x14b1cbd 0x1416ed0 0x1416cb2 0x22cf 0x14b1e99 0x1614e 0x160e6 0xbcade 0xbcfa7 0xbc266 0x3b3c0 0x3b5e6 0x21dc4 0x15634 0x139aef5 0x1484195 0x13e8ff2 0x13e78da 0x13e6d84 0x13e6c9b 0x13997d8 0x139988a 0x13626 0x1f0d 0x1e75)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: To OP: from all this, you can see that it's easy to make errors using Interface Builder and/because it has quite a bit of a learning curve. I generally recommend to beginners to learn how to make the UI programmatically and practice it as well in the first learning period - it's worth knowing what you are doing and what's happening "under the hoods" instead of trying to figure out stuff blindly.

Comment: Please read the fine message: ` reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is saying that the `setText` method was sent to a `UIView`, not a `UILabel`. Thus, it would appear that you may have accidentally linked the `IBOutlet` to the `UIView`, as opposed to the `UILabel` (which is easy to do if you manually wrote the `IBOutlet` line). So, go into Interface Builder, remove the `IBOutlet` link in the "outlets inspector" (the last tab on the right) for the `UIView` (probably on the main view), and link up the `IBOutlet` for the label.

By the way, you can avoid this sort of confusion if you refrain from manually writing that `IBOutlet` code, but rather <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the label to the .h file in the assistant editor (and Interface Builder will write the `IBOutlet` line of code for you and it will be fairly easily identified if you accidentally grabbed the wrong control). See [Make Connections Directly Between User Interface Objects and Your Source Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW10) in the *Xcode User Guide.*